# How to import the Kitware VTK dll from ActiViz to Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, paraview

I want to import a project from ParaView to Unity in order to improve the animations and to add more graphical effects. I am trying to copy the VTK dll from ActiViz to Unity, so I'll be able to work on the objects from ParaView in Unity, but didn't succeed. Unity doesn't recognize some of the dependent dll.
Does anyone know how to do that?

I've also tried other methods including installing the Unity ParaView plugin, and using Blender and other 3d software as a bridge to either Unity or Unreal Engine, but none of the methods worked.

Comment: Activiz is not developped as a plugin for blender. You may be interested by the following projects though :

Comment: https://github.com/cwant/VTKBlender https://github.com/tkeskita/BVtkNodes